# How do i WGET an image from a webaddress and store it on a remote ftp location as a cronjob on dd-wrt

Tags: ftp, wget, dd-wrt

From a DD-WRT router I want to create a cron-job that wget's an image from a remote location. This image is to be passed on to a remote FTP server for storage.
The process is to be repeated every minute, naming the destination image on the ftp with the current time :

```
wget: get file from -> http://37.***.9.95/fullsize.jpg 

ftp: put fullsize.jpg -> ftp://83.***.151.224/shares/camera/dateTimeNow.jpg
```

Where dateTimeNow is the current time. The ftp server for storage is not smart enough to have either cron nor something else than just FTP. the DD-WRT device however, has cron!

Comment: Do you want dateTimeNow.jpg to be that string or the actual date/time now?

Comment: Also can you confirm that dd-wrt provides cron facilities?

Comment: Can't you do this directly from the ftp server?

Comment: dd-wrt has cron: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/CRON

Comment: Do you have an FTP client available on your dd-wrt? Unless you have optware enabled and have installed one, I'd guess "no".

Answer (score 0):

If `curl` is available, something like this should work (untested; choose your own timestamp format for `date` command):

```
curl http://source/image.jpg | curl --upload-file - "ftp://destination/$(date +%F).jpg"
```